# Accessing the /mvc/public/index.php by just writing /mvc/ in the url and removing the .php

Tags: php, apache, model-view-controller, config

i am learning the mvc concepts and i found a video in which he does some changes, but the changes are not applied when i write the same code as he writes. I mean didn't write php but he did some changes in .htaccess file

my question is, my document root is `c/xampp/htdocs/mvc/public/index.php` , and when i write `localhost/mvc`, all the files and folders inside appears inside the mvc, i dont't want that. I want this to be redirected directly to the `mvc/public/index.php` page, and the extension .php should not appear in the url

**my code in index file**

```
echo "request url " . $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'];
```

and the `.htaccess` file is located in the public folder and is

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d


RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?$1 [L,QSA]
```

Comment: _"my document root is c/xampp/htdocs/mvc/public/index.php"_ - A document root should point to a folder, not a file so you should remove `index.php`. What OS are you running? Starting the path with `c/` looks odd. Also, if your document root is set to that, you shouldn't need to write `/mvc` in the URL. Is Apaches document root actually set to `c/xampp/htdocs/`?

Comment: Please check your support options with him, he might have other videos. Apart from that it sounds like its less about MVC but about server configuration. If you take care about that yourself, please do and consult the documentation. Otherwise forward your request to your system administrator.

Comment: @MagnusEriksson i mean, i use windows, and apache for the php. I have to type localhost/mvc/public/ and then enter to load the home page, but i want only the localhost/mvc/ and it should point go the home page, i dont want to type public folder, the tutor in videos is doing this. He is not writing /public/ and goes to home page (index.php) , i am doing this but i think something is missing and wrong in the apache config .htaccess file may be. I'm focusing on php but what is this .htaccess file, i dont know this

Comment: Tbh, I don't really care what "some guy in a video you found" does. As I've mentioned in my first comment, you should configure your Apache to have the document root set to `c:/xampp/htdocs/mvc/public/`, which you clearly don't have. Then you don't need to write the `/mvc/` part in the URL either. If you put the site online, you wouldn't want to write `example.com/mvc` to enter the site. Make your local environment work like you want the end result to work. Google something like "set up front controller with apache php" and read a few guides/articles to understand how things work.